# Proper options for openssl with simple ciphertext

Tags: encryption, ssl

Last weekend there was a cryptographic challenge where the ciphertext was the following hex:

```
FC 89 BF C2 B0 5F 1C 2E 64 B8 78 43 92 78 3A C9
```

I know for sure that this is encrypted using AES/Rijndael 128-bit ECB, the key is REDRYDER and a solution for this has already been posted to confirm this.  The plain text is FLAG=DAISY.  I wrote a simple PHP mcrypt script that decrypts this with no salt or no IV string and it decrypts properly. However, when I tried to use openssl, I don't get the plain text:

```
echo "0: FC 89 BF C2 B0 5F 1C 2E 64 B8 78 43 92 78 3A C9" | xxd -r | openssl aes-128-ecb -d -k REDRYDER -nosalt -nopad ; echo
```

This just outputs some binary data. I also tried passing the input through dd conv=swab to do a byte swap.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `openssl` command line tool is a demo of the OpenSSL library. It has a pretty haphazard interface and poor documentation. I don't recommend using it for anything other than testing the OpenSSL library. (Yes, there are people who manage CAs with `openssl`. I fear for their sanity.)

[AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) operates with a  key, not with a password. An AES-128 key is exactly 16 bytes.

The option `-k` doesn't take a key as input, it takes a password. This password is hashed to derive a key; the default is MD5 and it can be overridden with command line option `-md`. This isn't documented in the manual as far as I can see, you just have to read the source (`apps/enc.c`, call to `EVP_BytesToKey`). The MD5 digest produces a 16-byte value from any string, but this isn't what was used here. In this case, the key is actually `REDRYDER\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0` where the `\0` are null bytes.

The option `-K` lets you pass a key, in hexadecimal. If you pass fewer bytes than the key size, OpenSSL completes with null bytes. So to pass the key `REDRYDER\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`, you can pass `$(echo REDRYDER | od -An -tx1 | tr -d ' ')` which is `5245445259444552`.

The AES-128-ECB decryption operation of the ciphertext block FC89BFC2B05F1C2E64B8784392783AC9 with the key 52454452594445520000000000000000 yields 464c41473d4441495359000000000000 (using hexadecimal to represent the byte sequences). That's `FLAG=DAISY\0\0\0\0\0\0`.

For little cryptographic manipulations like these, I like the Python toplevel with the [Pycrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) library.

```
>>> from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> ciphertext = unhexlify('FC 89 BF C2 B0 5F 1C 2E 64 B8 78 43 92 78 3A C9'.replace(' ', ''))
>>> key = 'REDRYDER'.ljust(16, '\0')
>>> AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB).decrypt(ciphertext)
'FLAG=DAISY\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
echo '0: FC89BFC2B05F1C2E64B8784392783AC9' | xxd -r | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -d -nopad -nosalt -K 5245445259444552
```

I don't understand the input for the -k option, but if you convert your plain text key to hex (proper byte ordering) and use -K instead, it works.

openssl is voodoo!

Comment: -k accepts a password, which will be used to derive a key.
-K accepts a key (hex)